# Node.js leaking path info, how to solve it?

Tags: security, node.js

I have a webserver running... and if I curl from another server.  Something like that:

```
curl http://myserver.com/../../../../../etc/rsyslog.conf
```

then I can see the server info.

Is that a known problem?

---

UPDATE
here is my server code:

```
app = express.createServer(
            gzip.staticGzip(__dirname + '/public', {maxAge:5000 }),
            express.cookieParser(),
            express.bodyParser()

        );
```

---

got a fix like that:

```
var urlSecurity = function () {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.url.indexOf('../') >=0) {
            res.send('<div>Server Error</div>' , 500);
        } else if (req.url.indexOf('/..') >=0) {
            res.send('<div>Server Error</div>' , 500);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
}
app = express.createServer(
urlSecurity (),
            gzip.staticGzip(__dirname + '/public', {maxAge:5000 }),
            express.cookieParser(),
            express.bodyParser()

        );
```

is this good enough?

Comment: yes, directory traversal has been a problem in webservers since Day 1 of the web.

Answer (score 2):

You have a serious security flaw in your program.  Fix it immediately.

My best guess from the presented symptom is that you're doing something like:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var file = path.resolve('/path/to/files', request.url)
  fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(response)
})
```

This is extremely unwise!  Always sanitize user input.  In this case, it's quite easy:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var requestedFile = path.join('/', request.url);
  var file = path.join('/path/to/files', requestedFile)
  fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(response)
})
```

So, first we `path.join` the requested url onto `'/'`.  This will et rid of any `..` shenanigans, making it more sanitary.  Then, we `path.join` that onto our url.

Why use `path.join` rather than `path.resolve` in this case?  Because `path.join` just joins path parts, rather than resolving them, so a leading `/` won't have any ill effects.

Comment: > This will et rid of any .. shenanigans, making it more sanitary


Nope, it doesn't do that. The above code is still insecure.

Answer (score 2):

After the immediate fix, I have done a lot of testing.  and I confirm the following:

It is NOT a node problem primarily.  It is the gzippo module causing the problem.  Gzippo 0.1.3 is causing that problem.  0.1.4 has no problem.    NOt sure why is like that. but better not to use the older version of gzippo.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is `insecureFileName.split('/').pop()` will always returns only fileName.

```
'index.html'.split('/').pop() => 'index.html'
'../../../index.html'.split('/').pop() => 'index.html'
```

Comment: That _simply_ won't work on windows, but [my answer will](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51655632/344029) ;o)

Comment: @DJDaveMark what is windows? :D

Answer (score 0):

I sanitize user filenames with:

```
path.basename(filename);
```

e.g.:

```
const path = require('path');
let filename = '../../../../../../../etc/passwd';
filename = path.basename(filename); // 'passwd'
let pathToFile = path.join('/path/from/config/to', filename);
console.log(pathToFile); // 'path/from/config/to/passwd'
```